# Ubuntu 12.10 can't see eth0 after update from 12.04

Tags: 12.10, networking, ethernet

I just updated my laptop from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. After the update I could no longer get to the login screen, and after a while I realized that during the update my nvidia-drivers had been uninstalled. Apparently no other graphics driver is available.

So I started a root prompt to install nvidia-current only to find out that my internet connection is gone. I did the whole update with an ethernet cable plugged in, so it obviously worked in 12.04.

I tried to run `/etc/init.d/networking start` and `service networking start` to no avail.

`ifconfig -a` only shows the `lo` interface (Local Loopback).

`lspci` lists my ethernet controller:

`04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)`

I found some resources on the net suggesting I add

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to /run/network/interfaces (which didn't exist), so I did that and retried `service networking start`. However, it still doesn't work.

How do I make Ubuntu 12.10 recognize the ethernet connection?

Edit: I just ran `lshw -C network` which lists both my ethernet and wireless as UNCLAIMED. I heard this means there are no drivers available. I have a USB-drive with 12.04 on it, can I somehow extract the correct driver from there and install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started the root prompt from recovery mode in the oldest version of all installed kernels. That was a bad idead. I tried recovery mode with the newest kernel and ethernet started working. From there on I could install nvidia-current, and now I'm all set!